# How to pass a map with unique keys and array values (objects) in dart/flutter to a widget? or how to print it?

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap, widget

I have two questions: First of all how I can print the values of every key (example below). Second, how to pass/iterate it inside build to a custom widget?

I'm new to Dart and Flutter so any help will be appreciated.

```
var games = [
    {
      'sony': ['Bloodborne', 'Uncharted', 'GOW']
    },
    {
      'Nintendo': ['Mario', 'Zelda', 'Metroid']
    },
    {
      'Microsoft': ['Gears', 'Halo', 'Forza']
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `keys`, `values`, or `entries` object to achieve your goal.

```
for (var key in games.keys) print(key); // prints Sony Microsoft
for (var value in games.values) print(value); // prints your values
for (var entry in games.entries) {
  print(entry.key);
  print(entry.value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but I'm trying to use entries but it inst working Error: The getter 'entries' isn't defined for the class 'List<Map<String, List<String>>>'.  same for keys and values.

Comment: are you facing any issue while using entries? @LordAhmad

Comment: just use entry.value. entry.value is the list so you can use it easily

Comment: I don't understand, can you please update your answer above?

Comment: if entry.value is not applicable to your requirement then please provide your requirement

Comment: I have given you all possible ways in which you can use it to iterate the maps without key name in Dart.

Comment: I have copy pasted your answer on dartpad and it isnt working it gave me an error when using keys, values and entries.

Comment: To make it more clear I can't use games.keys, games.values or games.entries in (for in) it give me an error. I hope that make it clear for you what my issue is.